# How far into DC should I drive before catching Metro

Tags: trains, public-transport, driving, washington-dc

I plan to drive from Raleigh to Washington, DC. tomorrow (Sunday). My final destination is the Verizon Center. How far into DC should I drive before catching the metro?

Comment: This isn't clear. Why would you catch the metro at all? You could just drive all the way there. What do you intend to gain from using the metro?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: To avoid parking fees and traffic, one would assume.

Comment: @NateEldredge I generally find that if I make assumptions they are very frequently wrong. And I'm not very interested in spending a lot of time writing a wrong answer.